# auto adjustable css div content

Tags: css

I am trying to auto adjustable content with css divs. I am struck at div width. Below is my code. I am attaching screen what exactly my requirement should be. You can understand if you see the screen attached.

http://jsfiddle.net/266PG/44/

Please can anybody solve this problem.

This is what i want

[image]

Comment: Please tag your questions properly. People have had to edit the tags on your questions repeatedly because you're not using them appropriately and just filling them in for the sake of filling them in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this sample

```
<div id="outerDiv" class="autosize">
    <div id="innerDiv" runat="server" style="display: block">
        //Content...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#outerDiv
{
    min-height: 200px; 
}

div.autosize { display: table; width: 1px; }
div.autosize > div { display: table-cell; }
```

Comment: Pavan i wish taht you solved your problem, You can try with topstyle  link : http://topstyle.softonic.fr/

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
width: auto
```

and don't use fixed widths for inside divs.
Maybe you could define `max-width` property for outer div

Answer (score 0):

You may just use :

```
div {float:left;overflow:hidden;}
```